# jQuery: are these all statements true for find() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, selector, chaining

I'm curious if all the statements below are equivalent:

```
$(".postcell div").find(".post-taglist")
$(".postcell").find("div").find(".post-taglist")
$(".postcell").find("div .post-taglist")
```

and if it is valid for any number of `.find` in chain, any classess, ids etc.

The reason I ask is to be sure I don't miss anything when I replace selector with (variable + the rest part of the selector).

Comment: It can even be [an optimization](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all of those statements should return the same thing.

`$(".postcell").find("div").find(".post-taglist")` will be slightly slower than the other two.